# Add Validation for Model creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model

I have a Ruby on Rails project with 3 models: User, Group and Task.
The idea is that users can be in different groups and groups can have different users, so member is a table in between connecting them.

The problem is that when doing the seeding:

```
puts "Creating Users"
admin_one = User.create!(email: "jose@test.io", password: "1234567")
admin_two = User.create!(email: "joe@test.io", password: "1234567")

puts "Creating Groups"
group_one = Group.create!(name: "Test Group One", description: "blablabla", admin: admin_one)
group_two = Group.create!(name: "Test Group Two", description: "blablabla", admin: admin_two)

puts "Creating Tasks"
task_one = Task.create!(name: "Task 1", user: user_one, group: group_one, assignee: admin_one)
task_two = Task.create!(name: "Task 2", user: admin_one, group: group_one, assignee: admin_one)
# Test if we can create tasks for users not part of the group
task_two = Task.create!(name: "Task 3", user: admin_one, group: group_one, assignee: admin_two)
```

I realized that even if `admin_one` is part of `group_one`, I can still create a `Task` with the assignee being `admin_two` (who is not related to that group at all).

Is there a way to set it so that the task assignee's group needs to be one that the user is in? Is a `callback` the only option or there are other ways to implement the logic?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you plan to do authorization in your application? Do you use a gem like Pundit or Cancancan for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [custom validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) for this:

```
# in task model
validate :assignee_in_correct_group

def assignee_in_correct_group
  errors.add(:group_id, 'is not the same as assignee group id') unless assignee.groups.exist?(id: group.id)
end
```

Comment: This does't actually work since you're making a bad assumption that its a 1:1 association. The question states: "The idea is that users can be in different groups and groups can have different users".

Comment: You need `assignee.groups.exist?(id: group.id)`.